# Angry birds like Floating menu on Android

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to make a floating menu like the ones in Angry Birds home screen?

Here is a picture showing the menu buttons in collapsed mode (gear, up buttons). On tapping these buttons, the actual menu would expand, showing two or more round buttons.

[image]

Any links, clues is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's an image with a transparent background and you calculate its position based on time....

Although you could achieve it with standard widgets, maybe it would be a better idea to create a custom view and implement onDraw()

Comment: Can some one give an example of this floating menu, onclicking a button in current layout another layout(menu) should float from left to right animation on top of current layout button clicked..(Same as angry birds menu example)

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but I think that the entire thing is done in OpenGL.

Comment: Yes. It's a game so it must be done in OpenGL. But if you intend to use this menu style on something that isn't a game you'd be overkilling if you used OpenGL.

Comment: @PedroLoureiro: That might be true but he was asking how they were made or how you can make a similar thing. He didn't state for what. I have answered the question and not what I assume he might want to achieve.

Comment: it is overkilling to use OpenGL menu like this even in AngryBirds.. and of course it is not used here..

Comment: @Ewoks Enlighten me, because obviously you know more than me.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean don't get mad, I didn't want to offend anybody.. They used PlayN framework from google to make it (http://code.google.com/p/playn/).. They wrote Java code and framwork help them to make versions for different platforms.. Some of Game parts maybe use OpenGL for rendering but I would not say menu is one of them.. Cheers

Comment: @Ewoks I hope you're aware that they used PlayN only for their HTML5 port of Angry Birds, not for the Android version. Also, if you'd take a look at PlayN you'd find out that it actually translates to WebGL in the end, which leads us right back to where we started. Also, of course I get a little mad if people start down-voting based on uneducated guesses.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean Your choice is to be mad, mine is to say what I think about topic in a polite way. I am sharing my source of education so others can benefit and learn from it as well.. Cheers http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/AndroidPorts

Answer (score 0):

This is done within the XML of your 'game screen.' Assuming you've done a tutorial on OpenGL-ES, you should have an xml file that holds your custom GLSurfaceView. To add overlay items like buttons and, well.. anything, just add them to this xml file. Here's an example of a game I'm working on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

//This is your GLSurfaceView which will fill the whole screen
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/GLSurface" />


        //This layout will overlay the game
        <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sel"
            />

            <SeekBar
            android:paddingLeft="30px"
            android:paddingRight="30px"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/RotateBar"
            android:layout_width="180px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="180"
            />

            <Button
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Act"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Obviously this is modified (I don't have buttons floating in the center of the screen :P ) but you get the idea. Here's a link to good OpenGL-ES tutorial: [link](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/04/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-ii-building-a-polygon/)

Comment: Can some one give an example of this floating menu, onclicking a button in current layout another layout(menu) should float from left to right animation on top of current layout button clicked..(Same as angry birds menu example)